# Display an alert in jQuery for a few seconds then fade it out

Tags: javascript, jquery

When an AJAX call completes, I'd like to display a message to the user that shows for 3 seconds - and then fades out. Also, I want this message to show up right before the button he pressed - `#btnSubmit`.

Here's my code (it doesn't work - fades out the button instead of the message):

```
if(response == 'success') {
   $('#btnSubmit').before('<div>Success!</div>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fade out this dynamically generated element in jQuery?

Comment: A related library : http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/

Comment: can we see a bit more of the html?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `insertBefore()` instead of `before()`

```js
$(function() {
    $('<div>Success</div>')
    .insertBefore('#btnSubmit')
    .delay(3000)
    .fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="btnSubmit">button</button> 

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so that the effect and delay are applied to the new injected element.

Further information about `insertBefore()`: http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Comment: Also, i'd suggest removing the div when you're finished.

Comment: @KevinB would that be by adding `.remove()` to the end of the line?

Answer (score 6):

You were calling `fadeOut` on `#btnSubmit`.

```
$('#btnSubmit').before('<div id="success">Success!</div>');
$('#success').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Aha, thanks Afroman - I had trouble figuring out how to reference the alert, completely forgetting that I could use an `id='...'`. Nice thinking! It's a pity I can only pick one answer - and Fabrizio was first :/

Comment: @FloatingRock it should never be a matter of speed, just pick the answer you feel is right/elegant/performant/...

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan and yours was one line :)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I agree your answer is better, I just didn't want to copy it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#success").show();

setTimeout(function() { $("#success").hide(); }, 5000);
```